# How do I make my HtmlMenuItem open a URL in a new tab?

Tags: jsf, hyperlink, richfaces, menuitem, target

I am using richFaces 3.3.3.

I need to make a menuItem open a new tab with a simple URL ... for example google.com.
For now I tried this code:

```
HtmlMenuItem menuItem = new HtmlMenuItem();
menuItem.setid("id");
menuItem.setValue("My menu link new tab");

menuItem.setSubmitMode("server");
menuItem.setTarget("_blank");
menuItem.setOnClick("document.location.href='www.gooogle.com'");
```

But this makes my current tab is redirected to google, and open a new tab with the context in which I was.
I want to stay in my place, and the new tab "_blank" go to google.

I tried to replace onClick by onComplete, but this make new tab enter in my context too.
But don't execute
I tried to put an HtmlOutputLink as children of my menuItem, but not execute a click for outPutLink .. execute a click for menuItem ...

```
HtmlMenuItem menuItem = new HtmlMenuItem();
menuItem.setid("id");
menuItem.setValue("My menu link new tab");
HtmlOutputLink cLink = new HtmlOutputLink();
cLink.setTarget("_blank");
cLink.setValue("www.google.com");
menuItem.getChildren().add(cLink);
```

Comment: "But this makes my current tab is redirected to google, and open a new tab with the context in which I was. I want to stay in my place, and the new tab "_blank" go to google." - Of course. You are using document.location.href, which will change you the href of the current window. Also, setTarget will never work this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use only a OutputLink, something like:

```
HtmlOutputLink cLink = new HtmlOutputLink();
cLink.setValue("http://www.google.com");
cLink.setTarget("_blank");
HtmlOutputLabel label = new HtmlOutputLabel();
label.setValue("Google");
cLink.getChildren().add(label);
```

So, just add your link on some component.
Maybe HtmlMenuItem use javascript to open the page and your browser see it like a Pop-up.

Comment: So ty Lucas Merencia ^^ Good Job

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this? `<ui:include src="#{bean.link}"/>`

Your question is not really precise, so I just could come up with this idea ...

Comment: no.. i include menus dynamic, by code...i have a menu bar, and in my start code i include the menu itens.